# What was the gift from the Dr after saving the little sisters?

Tags: bioshock

I just saved my 3rd little sister in Bioshock, and the female doctor (I forget her name) said something along the lines of "I'm still not sure if you're friendly to us, but this Little Sister is going to give you something for helping us".

A message box then flashed up on the screen, but I happened to be shooting someone else at the time, and it closed before I even had a chance to read it.

What did it say?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For every 3 little sisters you save you receive a gift, which is located at the first Gatherer's Garden you come across after receiving the message. The gifts you receive are based on the below list ([source](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Little_Sister_Gifts#BioShock_Gifts)), with you receiving the next item on the list for every 3 sisters you save (starting with item 1).

> 1. Neptune's Bounty *(1st LS):*
>      Hypnotize Big Daddy Plasmid;
>      12 Armor-piercing Pistol Rounds.
> 2. Arcadia *(1st LS):* Safecracker Tonic; 12 Electric Buck.
> 3. Fort Frolic *(1st LS):* Hypnotize
>      Big Daddy 2 Plasmid; 4 First Aid Kits.
> 4. Hephaestus *(1st
>      LS):* 4 EVE Hypos; 6
>      Proximity Mines.
> 5. Olympus Heights *(1st LS):* Armored Shell 2 Tonic; 12 Incendiary Bolts.
> 6. Apollo Square
>      *(2nd LS):* Prolific Inventor Tonic; 150 Liquid Nitrogen.
> 7. Point Prometheus *(3rd LS):*
>      100 Antipersonnel Auto
>      Rounds; 4 First Aid Kits.

Therefore the gift you will receive this time is:

> Neptune's Bounty (1st LS): Hypnotize Big Daddy Plasmid; 12
>   Armor-piercing Pistol Rounds.

Comment: As the difference in gathered ADAM [is around 10%](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/ADAM), it seems that rescuing Little Sisters provides you with better rewards than killing them.